# why is typesetting Vietnamese in a text path impossible?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following is a medal design with circular text path. It works well with English language. But when the Vietnamese language is typset, errors are reported. Could you help me?

```
  \documentclass[12pt, border=11pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amsmath,  latexsym, amscd, amsthm}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
    \tikzset{my polygon/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#1,minimum size=4cm}}
    \usepackage{tikz}         
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text} 
    \usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
    \newcommand{\gear}[5]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {%
      [rotate=(\i-1)*360/#1]  (0:#2)  arc (0:#4:#2) {[rounded corners=1.5pt]
                 -- (#4+#5:#3)  arc (#4+#5:360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (360/#1:#2)
    }}  
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[color=black, line width=.372mm, line cap=round]
    \node[draw=black,minimum size=8.8cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=13] (a) {};

    % draw a black dot in each vertex
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,9}%
      \fill (a.corner \x) circle[radius=.2pt];
    \path 
        [rotate=190,postaction={decoration={text along path,text format delimiters={|}{|}, text={|\scshape\huge|\  TÌM KIẾM TÀI NĂNG TOÁN HỌC TRẺ \ },
          text align=fit to path,reverse path}, decorate}]
         circle[radius=3.508742cm] ; 

    \draw  (2.04,5.4) -- (-2.04,5.4);
    \draw  (-2.04,3.9) -- (-2.04,5.4);
    \draw  (2.04,3.9) -- (2.04,5.4);

    \draw [fill=gray,rounded corners] (-1.7,4.6) rectangle (1.7,5.05); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

[image]

You need to keep UTF-8 bytes together, pdftex will see each byte of a multi-byte encoded character as a separate token, normally that is Ok as they are all adjacent and combine to form a character but if the bytes are split up and spaced around the path the UTF8 decoding is broken completely. Grouping each letter means that the loop treats each letter as a unit.

```
  \documentclass[12pt, border=11pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amsmath,  latexsym, amscd, amsthm}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
    \tikzset{my polygon/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#1,minimum size=4cm}}
    \usepackage{tikz}         
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text} 
    \usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
    \newcommand{\gear}[5]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {%
      [rotate=(\i-1)*360/#1]  (0:#2)  arc (0:#4:#2) {[rounded corners=1.5pt]
                 -- (#4+#5:#3)  arc (#4+#5:360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (360/#1:#2)
    }}  
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[color=black, line width=.372mm, line cap=round]
    \node[draw=black,minimum size=8.8cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=13] (a) {};

    % draw a black dot in each vertex
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,9}%
      \fill (a.corner \x) circle[radius=.2pt];
    \path 
        [rotate=190,postaction={decoration={text along path,text format delimiters={|}{|}, text={|\scshape\huge|\ { }{T}{Ì}{M}{ }{K}{I}{Ế}{M}{ }{T}{À}{I}{ }{N}{Ă}{N}{G}{ }{T}{O}{Á}{N}{ }{H}{Ọ}{C}{ }{T}{R}{Ẻ}{ }\ },
          text align=fit to path,reverse path}, decorate}]
         circle[radius=3.508742cm] ; 

    \draw  (2.04,5.4) -- (-2.04,5.4);
    \draw  (-2.04,3.9) -- (-2.04,5.4);
    \draw  (2.04,3.9) -- (2.04,5.4);

    \draw [fill=gray,rounded corners] (-1.7,4.6) rectangle (1.7,5.05); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: How to make the words in the text path equally spaced along the circle in case I have fewer words on the other side of the medal?

Comment: That's an entirely different question and would apply equally to ascii text (and probably someone who knows tikz would be better to answer) @Thumbolt

Answer (score 7):

If you compile with `xelatex` there is absolutely no problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=11pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage{amsmath, latexsym, amscd, amsthm}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
    \tikzset{my polygon/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#1,minimum size=4cm}}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text}
\newcommand{\gear}[5]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {%%
      [rotate=(\i-1)*360/#1] (0:#2) arc (0:#4:#2) {[rounded corners=1.5pt]
                 -- (#4+#5:#3) arc (#4+#5:360/#1-#5:#3)} -- (360/#1:#2)
    }}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[color=black, line width=.372mm, line cap=round]
    \node[draw=black,minimum size=8.8cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=13] (a) {};

    % draw a black dot in each vertex
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,9}%
      \fill (a.corner \x) circle[radius=.2pt];
    \path
        [rotate=190,postaction={decoration={text along path,text format delimiters={|}{|}, text={|\scshape\huge|\ TÌM KIẾM TÀI NĂNG TOÁN HỌC TRẺ \ },
          text align=fit to path,reverse path}, decorate}]
         circle[radius=3.508742cm] ;

    \draw (2.04,5.4) -- (-2.04,5.4);
    \draw (-2.04,3.9) -- (-2.04,5.4);
    \draw (2.04,3.9) -- (2.04,5.4);

    \draw [fill=gray,rounded corners] (-1.7,4.6) rectangle (1.7,5.05);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]