# Decoration text (tikz). Problems with utf-8 (cyrillic)

Tags: tikz-pgf, font-encodings, cyrillic, tikz-decorations

Perhaps someone knows how to solve the following encoding problem (cyrillic) when using the package `tikz`? When using the library `decoration`, a compilation problem occurs with texts in the Cyrillic.

I would like to point out right away that I use `TeXLive` and as a `pdfLaTeX` compiler as well.

example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={170mm, 257mm},
left=2cm, right=1cm,
top=1cm, bottom=1.5cm, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                backgrounds,
                positioning,
                fit,
                petri,
                automata
            }

\usepgfmodule{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    auto, node distance = 1 cm and 1 cm, semithick,
    nStyl/.style    = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, minimum size = 1.2 cm, fill=gray!15, accepting}
}

\node[nStyl] (n1)                   {\makebox[4cm]{Текст\_1}};
\node[]      (n2)   [right = of n1] {\makebox[3cm]{}};
\node[nStyl] (n3)   [above = of n2] {\makebox[4cm]{Текст\_2}};


\draw[->, thick, postaction={decorate,
    decoration={raise=0.55ex,
        text along path,
        text align=center,
        text={Cyrillic text}}          % Here should be Cyrillic text, e.g. 'Текст'
}] (n1) to [bend right=60] (n3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It should be noted that this problem does not arise when using the Latin alphabet instead of the Cyrillic one.

[image]

---

The only way I know how to bypass this problem is to use a different compiler `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTex`. In that case, the preamble should look like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={170mm, 257mm},
left=2cm, right=1cm,
top=1cm, bottom=1.5cm, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}

... etc ...
```

However, I think it's more of a crutch than a solution. And I would like to understand the possibility of implementation on the basis of the `pdfLaTeX` compiler.

Comment: Welcome! Does loading the library `babel` help? (I can't even reproduce your screenshot when compiling your example. What compiler do you use?)

Comment: Hi! Do you mean add in preambule `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`? --- Unfortunately, that doesn't help.

You can use _overleaf.com_ for text reproduce. As a compiler I use `pdfLaTeX`.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351929/4427 Use `text={{Т}{е}{к}{с}{т}{}}` (don't forget the trailing `{}`).